# Getting Error While using Hibernate 4.0.1 + Spring 3.2.5 in java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp

I am trying to make Simple Crud Application using Spring hibernate. code is working but its not just Redirecting page. and its giving **404 Error** and i have check that file is in same path.

Here my Controller is

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


import com.verve.Model.EmployeeEntity;
import com.verve.service.EmployeeManager;

@Controller
public class EditEmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private com.verve.service.EmployeeManager employeeManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listEmployees(ModelMap map) 
    {
        map.addAttribute("employee", new EmployeeEntity());
        map.addAttribute("employeeList", employeeManager.getAllEmployees());

        return "editEmployeeList";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute(value="employee") EmployeeEntity employee, BindingResult result) 
    {
        employeeManager.addEmployee(employee);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete/{employeeId}")
    public String deleteEmplyee(@PathVariable("employeeId") Integer employeeId)
    {
        employeeManager.deleteEmployee(employeeId);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    public void setEmployeeManager(EmployeeManager employeeManager) {
        this.employeeManager = employeeManager;
    }
}
```

and threw that my Method is called. 
and my index.jsp is

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    <jsp:forward page="/"></jsp:forward>
</body>
</html>
```

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringHibernate3.2.5H4.0.1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

my applicationservlet.xml means in mycase file name is diff

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.verve.Controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.verve.Dao.EmployeeDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="employeeManager" class="com.verve.service.EmployeeManagerImpl"></bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

i am not getting any error in console. but m getting error 404 in browser and this warning.

```
Hibernate: select employeeen0_.ID as ID2_, employeeen0_.EMAIL as EMAIL2_, employeeen0_.FIRSTNAME as FIRSTNAME2_, employeeen0_.LASTNAME as LASTNAME2_, employeeen0_.TELEPHONE as TELEPHONE2_ from EMPLOYEE employeeen0_
Jul 18, 2014 2:58:20 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringHibernate3.2.5H4.0.1/WEB-INF/view/editEmployeeList.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'employee'
```

here i can see controller is called but getting error. i have checked alost please help.

in my view there is 4 jsp file. from which redirected

```
editEmployeeList.jsp

<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3 hibernate integration example on www.howtodoinjava.com</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Employee Management Screen : Spring 3 hibernate integration example on www.howtodoinjava.com</h2>

<form:form method="post" action="add" commandName="employee">

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="firstname"><spring:message code="label.firstname"/></form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="lastname"><spring:message code="label.lastname"/></form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="email"><spring:message code="label.email"/></form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="telephone"><spring:message code="label.telephone"/></form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="telephone" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.add"/>"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> 
</form:form>


<h3>Employees</h3>
<c:if  test="${!empty employeeList}">
<table class="data">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${employeeList}" var="emp">
    <tr>
        <td>${emp.lastname}, ${emp.firstname} </td>
        <td>${emp.email}</td>
        <td>${emp.telephone}</td>
        <td><a href="delete/${emp.id}">delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</c:if>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ***change applicationservlet.xml to employee-servlet.xml***

2***.change in web.xml***

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml</param-value>

    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>employee</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

3***.change in employee-servlet.xml***

Comment: then its giving StackOverFlow Error :(

Comment: change in employee-servlet.xml

<context:component-scan base-package="com.verve" />

Comment: well its just that i have renamed my project so was not able to find path :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/employee-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

change the name of file **applicationservlet.xml to employee-servlet.xml** and check  your code in **employee-servlet.xml**.

```
 <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

once you redirect any value in above **org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver** class  it will attach .jsp as suffix to value and redirect or return the particular  file which is present in the **path : /WEB-INF/view/**. in your controller change **return "redirect:/";** to particular file name.

Answer (score 0):

Change your RequestMapping here to something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editEmployee", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listEmployees(ModelMap map) 
    {
        map.addAttribute("employee", new EmployeeEntity());
        map.addAttribute("employeeList", employeeManager.getAllEmployees());

        return "editEmployeeList";
    }
```

Change your `url-pattern` in `web.xml` to

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

I dont know what you want to do with this

```
<jsp:forward page="/"></jsp:forward>
```

But if you want to display the `editEmployeeList.jsp`

place this in somewhere in index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<a href="<c:url value="/editEmployee"/>">click</a>
```